# how to handle blow up in the numerical solution to this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

The PDE is as below:

$$
h(t, \alpha), t\in[0, 60], \alpha \in [-300, 300]
$$
$$
\partial_th+0.04\alpha-200\alpha \partial_\alpha h+0.5\partial_{\alpha\alpha}h=0
$$
with terminal condition:
$$
 h(T, \alpha) = 0.02, \qquad \text{where}\qquad T=60
$$
what is $h(0, \alpha)$?

So I use a grid on t and $\alpha$ to back induct $ h(0, \alpha) $.
Now the problem is the coefficient of $\partial_\alpha h$, which is $-200\alpha$, is very big.
And after several steps, it will blow up.

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try the solution $$
h(t,\alpha) = 0.02 + 0.0002\, \alpha\, \big(1 - e^{200\, (t-60)}\big) .
$$